# why am I getting transaction_status = "Failed" on paypal Mass Payment using SOAP?

Tags: c#, soap, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

In Sandbox Mass paypal payment
I am getting Transaction_status = Failed

```
var payout = new Payout
{                    
    sender_batch_header = new PayoutSenderBatchHeader
    {
        sender_batch_id = "batch_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8),
        email_subject = "You have a payment"
    },

    items = new List<PayoutItem>
    {
        new PayoutItem
        {
            recipient_type = PayoutRecipientType.EMAIL,
            amount = new Currency
            {

                value = dblAmount.ToString(),
                currency = paypalSettings.currency_code
            },
            receiver = paypalSettings.strReceiverEmail,
            note = "Thank you.",
            sender_item_id = paypalSettings.strReservationID
        }                    
    }
};               
var apiContext = GetAPIContext(paypalSettings);
var createdPayout = payout.Create(apiContext, true);

return createdPayout.items[0].transaction_status.ToString();
```

in return I am getting "Failed".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you step through the code as well as provide a better `Error Message` also `PayPal has Support` for their product as well, have you consulted them.. since we don't know the methods or what they look like what does this method look like `GetAPIContext`

Comment: Thanks @eshan   That was exactly what I need now it's going perfectly and I got **Transaction_status = Success.** Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the mass payment or payout you need to make sure that sender has enough PayPal balance . It won't take the money from credit/debit or bank account . You must have sufficient PayPal balance .

If this is not the case , you can share the complete response you got from the PayPal .